# Is it possible to separate the ... in a function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a simple function in R that uses `...`. Is is possible to separate the inputs?

```
simple_paste <- function(...){
  paste0(..., collapse = "_x_")
}

simple_paste("hello", "world")
```

As an output, instead of `"helloworld"` I would like `"hello_x_world"`

Comment: You need `paste` intstead of `paste0`

Comment: And `sep` instead of `collapse`: `paste(..., sep  = "_x_")`

Comment: you don't need `simple_paste`. `paste` already does what you want.

Comment: the point of `simple_paste` was to practice with `...`